Kotlin Multiplatform Ktor making POST request on iOS side
I'm stuck in some strange problem using KMP & Ktor. I have API class on shared module for network interaction. One of methods, for example:
suspend fun destinations(departure: DeparturePoint, callback: (DestinationsResponse) -> Unit) {
        var result: DestinationsResponse? = null

        try {
            val param = mapOf(
                "server" to departure.server,
                "departure" to departure.id,
            )

            result = client().post("$baseUrl/api/v2/routes/destinations") {
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                setBody(param)
            }.body()

            Instance.api.destinations = result?.data ?: listOf()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            log.e { "~~~ destinations exception: ${e.message}" }
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            log.e { "~~~ destinations throwable: ${t.message}" }
        } finally {
            callback(result ?: DestinationsResponse())
        }
    }

DestinationsResponse class definition:
@ExperimentalSerializationApi
@ExperimentalStdlibApi
@Serializable
data class DestinationsResponse(
    var ok: Boolean = false,
    var error: ErrorInfo? = null,
    var data: List<BusStop>? = listOf()
) {
    @Suppress("Unused")
    fun toJson() = Json.encodeToString(this)
}

calling this method on Android side is always successful, but on iOS/Swift side it's always fails with logs:
E/API: ~~~ destinations throwable: There was an error during file or class initialization 
Swift usage:
Instance.companion.api.destinations(departure: departurePoint, callback: { _ in
// some code
}, completionHandler: { _ in })

I've tried to change types/encodings, but as far as I can see, making any POST request  will fail with the same diagnose.
What is the reason? What I'm doing wrong? How to fix?
Thank you in advance!

Can you please try to deserialize the JSON directly with the kotlinx.serialization (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)?

I've just found the problem is in the serialization process of Map<>.
when I replace Map with custom object like this:
    @Serializable
    data class Params(val server: String = "", val departure: String = "", )

    try {
        result = client().post("$baseUrl/api/v2/routes/destinations") {
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            setBody(Params(departure.server, departure.id))
        }.body()

everything works well both on Android and iOS side.
It's very strange!
